# My docker Container goes to exited state when i restart my Windows 10 machine restart

Tags: docker

I have installed Docker in my Windows 10. When i restart my machine the docker container i have created automatically goes to exited state, how to prevent this from happening. I need the container running when i restart the machine

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

Comment: Can i modify the existing container with restart or i have to create a new one. ?

Comment: Deleting and recreating a container is very routine and I'd just do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Also where to place my cacerts file in Docker container, I see a Folder named /etc/ssl. Can i copy the cacerts file from my Host Win 10 machine to this location, Will it work.